# Applying client specific labeling and logos while building Angular 6 app

Tags: angular, branding

We have a product it have multiple clients, with their specific labeling and logos. So what i need to do is to build my app with client specific configurations. How can I achieve this in optimal way? currently what i am doing is putting variables in Enviroment.ts file, so i have to make enviroment file for each client.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  owner: 'Advisor',
  logoUrl: '/assets/img/orion_logo.png'
};
```

i looking for a better and recommended way to this task.

Comment: Define "better" and "optimal". What's the problem with your current solution? What should be improved and why?

Comment: It would be slightly more helpful if you showed us your work instead of providing just the environment snippet. Where and how are you placing that logo?

Comment: Sir we normally use environment files for setting up configuration of different environments like dev, qa, production. so i just need to know is having client specific information in environment  file appropriate or is there any opinionated way to this in angular? better in term of implementation/code quality.

Comment: @R.D i am placing the logo in HTML template of navbar component

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what environment files are made for.

In a sense, the development, production and testing environment files which come with Angular's CLI are actually building for different clients:

- some clients want the build made quickly and easy for debugging (you, as a developer)
- some clients want the build to redirect to a mock backend server or another source (the e2e tests)
- some clients want to have a perfectly working and optimized build (visitors)

Having clients who want different colors, fonts, logos, etc. falls into this category.